# SSL on apache; the requested URL was not found

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.4, redirect, documentroot

I am setting up SSL on my Apache/2.4.6 RHEL server. In `httpd.conf`, have VirtualHosts as shown below...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName foo.bar
    Redirect permanent / https://foo.bar
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/file

    ServerName foo.bar

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/file

</VirtualHost>
```

When I comment out DocumentRoot in httpd.conf outside of the VirtualHosts, the web browser returns error 404 `The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Do I need to have a DocumentRoot outside of `VirtualHost *:443`? If not, what is going on when I comment it out?

Comment: Why would you want to remove that statement from the 443 virtualhost? It's there for a reason: to tell Apache where to find the documents it needs to serve. If you remove it, it will most likely fall back to a globally defined path or possibly a default, but it most likely won't work.

Comment: Hi, I agree. I do not want to remove DocumentRoot from VirtualHost 443, but when I do not have a DocumentRoot defined outside of the virtualhosts above the error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had ssl.conf set up separately and incorrectly. Fixed the ssl.conf and removed the VirtualHost for 443 from httpd.conf, and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You will have in some apache config a DocumentRoot defined, which is likely not accessible by the server, you can check this by issuing for RHEL flavours:

```
 /usr/sbin/httpd -S
```

and Debian

```
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S
```

It should contain a variable:

```
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
```

You can either adjust this or set one in the virtual host section (I would prefer this one, being set to the same of the SSL vhost).